# Containers spawns in different position in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

Problem: When I enter text in containers they get in different position (and it's not what I want). When they have same amount of characters they get in the same position. Otherwise you will see in fiddle, my code is listed there.

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lsg4mj9/2/

**CSS CODE:**

```
body {
    background:#1a1a1a;
    color: black; font-family: Optima,Segoe,"Segoe UI",Candara,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif; }

.header {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:150px;
    background: rgba(0,173,255,0.5);
    border:2px solid white;

} 

#header h1 {
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    color: white;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    font-size: 51px;
    line-height:20px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    font-weight:bold; } 

#header h2 {
    font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight: bold; }

.container {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:233px;
    height:480px;
    background: rgba(0,193,255,0.5);
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-top: 20px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease;
    transition: background-color 2s ease; }

.container:hover {
        background: rgba(0,153,155,0.5);

}

.container:hover span {
        color:red;

}

.container:hover span{
     -o-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 500ms; }

#container h1 {
    margin-top:-15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight: bold; }

.footer {
    border:2px solid white;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:75px;
    background: rgba(0,193,255,0.5);
    font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

Adding some extra characters to bypass

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't link to an actual fiddle. Make sure you hit the save button on the fiddle and it'll give it a unique url which you can post here.

Comment: Edited, sorry. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default vertical alignment for `inline-block` elements are `baseline`. Apply `vertical-align:top;` to your container to achieve the desired result.

```
.container {
display:inline-block;
margin:0px auto;
width:233px;
height:480px;
background: rgba(0,193,255,0.5);
border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
border-top: 20px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
float:center;
-webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease;
transition: background-color 2s ease;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqx5pLve/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`float:center` doesn't exist. I think you need to change to `float:left` and add 'clear:both` to your footer. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6uhupc6/